# Theorem VI in GENERAL INVESTIGATIONS OF CURVED SURFACES by Gauss

Tags: curves, surfaces

I am reading Gauss's paper [*GENERAL INVESTIGATIONS
OF CURVED SURFACES*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/36856/36856-pdf.pdf), but encountered a problem in Theorem VI (p. 4).

How does the following observation come from? In Gauss's notation, $LL'$ denotes the angle between the two vectors.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: "angle between the two vectors" must be wrong: From the context, this means the arc of the great circle between the non-antipodal points $L, L'$ (where the arc is chosen to be less than $\pi$ in length). At the same time, the notation $LL'$ can also mean the length of that arc, Gauss is sloppy here. the formulae themselves appear to be the spherical laws of cosines. I have no idea if Gauss already proved these or not.

Comment: @MoisheKohan By "angle between the two vectors", I mean the angle between $OL$ and $OL'$, where $O$ is the center of the ball. Perhaps we share the same understanding about this. Gauss didn't give a proof. But thanks for your comment, I realized how to get them.